# How to postpone redrawing on startup?

Tags: init-file

On startup I can see the fonts and color scheme before my own are loaded in.

Is it possible to drawing the interface until a certain moment when settings are loaded?

---

Incase it's important: *Linux, GTK3 UI, 26.2 (latest at time of writing)*

Comment: This sounds like a case where it might be relevant to cite your platform (and your Emacs version).

Comment: Added this info, although emacs might support it on all platforms.

Comment: I remember having the same issue on Windows, so I assume it will be the same on any platform with a graphical Emacs. Color themes are the worst offenders here, as I get this problem even with Emacs in a terminal. I have no clue whether there's a way to solve this, as I assume it would require making changes to code that loads the init file, which is quite invasive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The initial frame is created *before* your `~/.emacs` file is read, so it necessarily uses the default "theme" first and only later updates to the appearance you chose.

In Emacs-27, you can customize appearance in `~/.emacs.d/early-init.el` which is loaded before the GUI is initialized, which should avoid this problem.
[ Of course, since it's loaded before the GUI is setup, it can't do GUI-dependent operations.  It doesn't even know if a GUI will be used at all.  ]